# Selecting Contact using Id is not returning a row

Tags: apex, trigger

Can anyone see anything wrong here? This query of the contact by the Id is returning nothing. The contact definitely exists and the Id is without a doubt correct.

```
List<Contact> joiningStudent = [select Id, FirstName, LastName, FromAPI__c from Contact where Id= '0032C0000037mDPQAY'];
```

Here's the full trigger:

```
trigger SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam on Active_Student__c (after insert) {

    for (Active_Student__c rosterRecord : Trigger.new) {  

        //go fetch the student's contact record so we can get a bit of their information to send an email.
        //List<Contact> joiningStudent = [select Id, FirstName, LastName, FromAPI__c from Contact where Id = :rosterRecord:Student_Name__c];    
        List<Contact> joiningStudent    = [select Id, FirstName, LastName, FromAPI__c from Contact where Id = '0032C0000037mDPQAY'];

        if (rosterRecord.Faculty_Approved__c == 'Pending' && joiningStudent[0].FromAPI__c) {
            List<String> allEmails = new List<String>();

            for (Contact c : [SELECT Id, Email from Contact where Id in (select Student_Name__c
                                                                         FROM Active_Student__c 
                                                                         where School__c= :rosterRecord.School__c and Manage_Student_Accounts__c=true
                                                                         and Faculty_Approved__c = 'Approved' and End_Date__c = null
                                                                         and Student_or_Alumni_Status__c='Student')]) 
            {
                allEmails.add(c.Email);
            }

            for (Contact c : [select Id, Email from Contact where Id in (select Faculty__c from Faculty_Information__c
                                                                         where School__c= :rosterRecord.School__c and End_Date__c = null
                                                                         and (Faculty_Type__c ='Primary Faculty Advisor' or Faculty_Type__c = 'Co-Faculty Advisor'))]) 
            {
               allEmails.add(c.Email);                                                              
            }

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setToAddresses(allEmails);    
            mail.setReplyTo('no-reply@enactus.org');
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Enactus');
            mail.setSubject(joiningStudent[0].FirstName + ' ' + joiningStudent[0].LastName + ' wants to join your Enactus team!');
            mail.setHtmlBody('Please visit ... and navigate to "Team" to approve or deny them.');

            List<Messaging.Email> emails = new List<Messaging.Email>();
            emails.add(mail);

            Messaging.sendEmail(emails);       
        }
    }    
}
```

Here's the text of the log:

```
38.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
10:50:53.0 (305787)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|00570000003FaI8|tevans@enactus.org.tony|Central Standard Time|GMT-05:00
10:50:53.0 (341110)|EXECUTION_STARTED
10:50:53.0 (344597)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p2C000000Cyjk|TestSendEmailStudentJoinedTeam.testSendEmail
10:50:53.0 (604244)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[72]|Bytes:3
10:50:53.0 (649659)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[77]|Bytes:152
10:50:53.0 (666188)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[342]|Bytes:408
10:50:53.0 (681967)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[355]|Bytes:408
10:50:53.0 (695858)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[467]|Bytes:48
10:50:53.0 (723196)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[139]|Bytes:6
10:50:53.0 (735590)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:24
10:50:53.0 (759013)|METHOD_ENTRY|[3]|01p2C000000Cyjk|TestSendEmailStudentJoinedTeam.TestSendEmailStudentJoinedTeam()
10:50:53.0 (763402)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[3]
10:50:53.0 (768396)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[3]
10:50:53.0 (773737)|METHOD_EXIT|[3]|TestSendEmailStudentJoinedTeam
10:50:53.0 (817051)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[50]|Bytes:5
10:50:53.0 (850497)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[56]|Bytes:5
10:50:53.0 (857179)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[64]|Bytes:7
10:50:53.0 (892123)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[6]
10:50:53.0 (893621)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[8]
10:50:53.0 (896678)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[8]|Bytes:18
10:50:53.0 (914096)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[8]|accountId|String|false|false
10:50:53.0 (942876)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[8]|accountId|"0012C000004iTx0QAE"
10:50:53.0 (945693)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[9]
10:50:53.0 (947839)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[9]|Bytes:18
10:50:53.0 (951014)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[9]|studentId|String|false|false
10:50:53.0 (955292)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[9]|studentId|"0032C0000037mDPQAY"
10:50:53.0 (956693)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[15]
10:50:53.0 (1005820)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[15]|Bytes:4
10:50:53.0 (1110716)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[15]|pendingRoster|Active_Student__c|true|false
10:50:53.0 (1127354)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[15]|pendingRoster|{}|0x58b5d123
10:50:53.0 (1129571)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[16]
10:50:53.0 (1190076)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[16]|Bytes:4
10:50:53.0 (1296256)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[16]|this.Start_Date__c|"2016-10-18T00:00:00.000Z"|0x58b5d123
10:50:53.0 (1300240)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[17]
10:50:53.0 (1312055)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[17]|Bytes:4
10:50:53.0 (1345718)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[17]|this.Student_Name__c|"0032C0000037mDPQAY"|0x58b5d123
10:50:53.0 (1348277)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[18]
10:50:53.0 (1351079)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[18]|Bytes:7
10:50:53.0 (1369003)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[18]|this.Student_or_Alumni_Status__c|"Student"|0x58b5d123
10:50:53.0 (1371259)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[19]
10:50:53.0 (1373259)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[19]|Bytes:7
10:50:53.0 (1387623)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[19]|this.Faculty_Approved__c|"Pending"|0x58b5d123
10:50:53.0 (1389524)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[20]
10:50:53.0 (1393088)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[20]|Bytes:4
10:50:53.0 (1416643)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[20]|this.School__c|"0012C000004iTx0QAE"|0x58b5d123
10:50:53.0 (1418738)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[22]
10:50:53.0 (1441639)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[22]|Bytes:8
10:50:53.0 (1448709)|DML_BEGIN|[22]|Op:Insert|Type:Active_Student__c|Rows:1
10:50:53.0 (1468303)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
10:50:53.0 (36684904)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q2C000000Ccu6|SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam on Active_Student trigger event AfterInsert for [a192C000000GwHv]
10:50:53.0 (36750100)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
10:50:53.0 (36915169)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
10:50:53.0 (36929544)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1]|this|SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam|true|false
10:50:53.0 (36967213)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1]|this|{}|0x4678c716
10:50:53.0 (37009434)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
10:50:53.0 (37017309)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1]|this|SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam|true|false
10:50:53.0 (37024988)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1]|this|{}|0x4678c716
10:50:53.0 (37030359)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
10:50:53.0 (37355553)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[3]|Bytes:5
10:50:53.0 (37383600)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[3]|rosterRecord|Active_Student__c|true|false
10:50:53.0 (37693135)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[3]|rosterRecord|{"Student_or_Alumni_St (7 more) ...":"Student","LastModifiedDate":"2016-10-18T15:50:53.000Z","IsDeleted":false,"Enrolled__c":false,"Register_for_Team_Ev (7 more) ...":false,"Service_Leadership__ (1 more) ...":false,"School__c":"0012C000004iTx0QAE","Faculty_Approved__c":"Pending","Student_Name__c":"0032C0000037mDPQAY","Name":"168156","SystemModstamp":"2016-10-18T15:50:53.000Z","Project_Partnership_ (2 more) ...":false,"Has_Permissions__c":false,"Manage_Student_Accou (6 more) ...":false,"CreatedById":"00570000003FaI8AAK","Update_Team_Data__c":false,"CreatedDate":"2016-10-18T15:50:53.000Z","Project_Management__ (1 more) ...":false,"Id":"a192C000000GwHvQAK","Primary_Contact__c":false,"LastModifiedById":"00570000003FaI8AAK","Start_Date__c":"2016-10-18T00:00:00.000Z"}|0x490c84df
10:50:53.0 (37714823)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[3]
10:50:53.0 (37716498)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[8]
10:50:53.0 (37727937)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[8]|Bytes:4
10:50:53.0 (37758985)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[8]|ids|List<String>|true|false
10:50:53.0 (37800045)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
10:50:53.0 (37815716)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[8]|ids|{"s":1,"v":[]}|0x47464fd
10:50:53.0 (37818493)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[9]
10:50:53.0 (37896009)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
10:50:53.0 (37906948)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[10]
10:50:53.0 (37912114)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:76
10:50:53.0 (37923203)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:4
10:50:53.0 (37948383)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:7
10:50:53.0 (38181414)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[10]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, FromAPI__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :tmpVar1
10:50:53.0 (40580537)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[10]|Rows:0
10:50:53.0 (40599226)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:4
10:50:53.0 (40608566)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:0
10:50:53.0 (40664105)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:4
10:50:53.0 (40675347)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[10]|joiningStudent|List<Contact>|true|false
10:50:53.0 (40692065)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[10]|joiningStudent|{"s":1,"v":[]}|0xe11c4d1
10:50:53.0 (40808340)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[12]|Bytes:31
10:50:53.0 (40968163)|FATAL_ERROR|System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Trigger.SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam: line 12, column 1
10:50:53.0 (40975361)|FATAL_ERROR|System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Trigger.SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam: line 12, column 1
10:50:53.41 (41020901)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
10:50:53.41 (41020901)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 1 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 1 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

10:50:53.41 (41020901)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

10:50:53.0 (41928293)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam on Active_Student trigger event AfterInsert for [a192C000000GwHv]
10:50:53.0 (43781636)|DML_END|[22]
10:50:53.0 (43871752)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[22]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Trigger.SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam: line 12, column 1: []
10:50:53.0 (44184070)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[22]|Bytes:291
10:50:53.0 (44241248)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Trigger.SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam: line 12, column 1: []

Class.TestSendEmailStudentJoinedTeam.testSendEmail: line 22, column 1
10:50:53.0 (44249034)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Trigger.SendEmailUponStudentRequestToJoinTeam: line 12, column 1: []

Class.TestSendEmailStudentJoinedTeam.testSendEmail: line 22, column 1
10:50:53.44 (44257692)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
10:50:53.44 (44257692)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 1 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

10:50:53.44 (44257692)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

10:50:53.0 (44279254)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|TestSendEmailStudentJoinedTeam.testSendEmail
10:50:53.0 (45191507)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the text version of the log line which matters?

Comment: So what happens if you visit `/0032C0000037mDPQAY`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson it takes me right to the contact.

Comment: Why are you hard-coding the Id? This trigger violates many `Apex` best practices, including that you should never hard-code an Id anywhere, ever. (you should also look at logic-less triggers and trigger handler pattern)

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'm not hard-coding the Id. I'm just trying to figure out why it's not working. Look at the full trigger and the commented line directly above the one with the hardcoded ID.

Comment: What happens when you run this query from the developer console? Is this only happening with some users, and not other users?

Comment: Oh yeah, and SOQL in a `for` loop, and `Messaging.sendEmail` in a loop. If you ever run this trigger with more than 10 records, it's going to explode.

Comment: Is it not working for that one specific Contact? Or any and all Contacts?

Comment: @battery.cord All of this was from the dev console. It looks like my test class is failing to insert my test record properly. I thought the trigger was failing not the record insert. The error was always "List index out of bounds: 0" @ line #10 in the trigger which lead me to think the trigger failure was causing the record to not get inserted not the other way around. There are only 5 required fields on that object so I'm wondering if I'm not supplying the correct data type or something.

Comment: @TonyEvans I figured it out... see my final answer. You need to physically insert new records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several readings, it looks like the following is true:

- You're doing this in a unit test.
- You're using isolation mode (SeeAllData=false)
- <strike>You're creating Contact and Active_Student__c records like you should.</strike>
- You're hard-coding ID values in your unit test (accountId and studentId).

The hard-coded ID won't work because you're creating a new record every unit test-- it will have a different value every time you run the test.

The original, now-commented query appears to have a typo:

```
= :rosterRecord:Student_Name__c
```

This shouldn't compile, but even if it did, I'd expect it to behave badly, because of the second colon. Instead, it should be:

```
= :rosterRecord.Student_Name__c
```

---

Edit: Your unit test, while not included, indicates that you're using hard-coded ID values there. Interestingly, I have just mocked up a unit test and trigger that proves that ID values are not checked for existence until after the "before insert" trigger event.

You need to actually create Account and Contact records, and not just use hard-coded Id values.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The =:rosterRecord:Student_Name__c was a typo. I think i changed it when it was a comment because when I uncommented the line it wouldn't compile.

The hardcoded Id was just to make sure :rosterRecord.Student_Name__c wasn't causing a problem. I was just trying to make the query as basic as I could. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @TonyEvans Isolation mode + hard-coded ID values in your unit test class = Bad Idea(TM). You need to actually create a new account and contact in your unit test.

Comment: I saw your edit. I am using hard coded account and contact ids in my test because, frankly, it just seemed the fastest way to do it. It definitely didn't turn out that way. I'll test it myself just to verify that that's the issue. Another question. Why would the hardcoded values not work in my test, but it would when creating the records from the SF UI?

Comment: @TonyEvans Because of Isolation Mode (see the first link in my answer).

Comment: I'm a totally noob at this. In regard to my last question about the test vs ui, i'm assuming that's because of isolation mode?